# How do I fix "Error starting VisualVM" in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, jvisualvm

I tried the following steps:
In Eclipse under `Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching > VisualVM Configuration`.

Next to VisualVM Executable, I choose Browse. and select `jvisualvm.exe` from `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin`.

Now when I press Run I get an `Error Starting VisualVM - You are running VisualVM using Java Runtime Environment (JRE).`

Tried Editing 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\lib\visualvm\etc\visualvm.conf' by replacing #jdkhome="/path/to/jdk" with #jdkhome=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32 and I'm still getting the same error.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open "visualvm_directory/etc/visualvm.conf" file and set the JDK path in the "jdkhome" attribute

ex.: jdkhome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67

Comment: Thanks for the help.. From C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\lib\visualvm\etc\visualvm.conf, I replaced #jdkhome="/path/to/jdk" with #jdkhome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32 but I still get the same error. Strange..

Comment: Just to make sure .... have you removed the "#" too? If not, replace "#jdkhome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32" for "jdkhome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32"

Comment: In Eclipse under "Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching > VisualVM Configuration", there's another option "JDK Home". This was actually pointing to my JRE directory. Changing this to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32 got it running. Now the error message makes sense. Your advice helped me figure it out. Problem solved! Thanks again!

Comment: @iamnotapsycho Your solution was the only one who helped me, you should create your own answer.